# Does anything "break" in physics if you allow for instant (faster-than-light) communication?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-information, speed-of-light, faster-than-light, thought-experiment

Assume that two entities, Alice and Bob, can communicate thoughts literally instantly. If Bob thinks "Alice, I want you to jump", then Alice (many, many light-years away) will know that thought instantly (e.g. that thought won't take years to communicate).

Does anything completely break/explode in our model of physics if beings like Alice and Bob exist? For example, if I said that Alice could run faster than the speed of light, that would break things because it would imply more than infinite energy is being produced (to accelerate a mass from stationary to faster-than-light).

I just want to know if the possibility of instantaneous (faster-than-light) communication brings about any major contradictions in known physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would allow Alice to send a message back in time to herself via Bob if they were moving relative to one another. This is because if they are moving they have different definitions of "simultaneous", and one result of that is that each would find the other's clock to be running slowly. If they were moving apart quickly enough then relative to Alice, when her clock reads 8 o'clock then Bob's reads 4 o'clock; but relative to Bob when his clock reads 4 o'clock Alice's reads 2 o'clock. This is called the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

Comment: Thank you! One last question, if I can. Isn't the situation completely symmetric between Bob and Alice? How is Alice sending messages back in time through her instant communication, but Bob is sending them into the future?

Comment: The situation is completely symmetric -- they both send into the other's past. That's the root of the problem. Alice sends into Bob's past, and then Bob sends to Alice's past, so the result is that Alice can (via Bob) send to her own past.

Answer (score 2):

For one, [causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Causality_and_prohibition_of_motion_faster_than_light) is now broken - in some frame, Alice will know that Bob wants her to jump before Bob has made that thought. This is clearly paradoxical.

Comment: I have always felt that a causal universe is a good thing to live in, although acausality might have some entertaining aspects... +1. -NN