# What would "break" in reality if I had a perpetual motion device?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, faster-than-light, perpetual-motion

Let's say aliens came and gave me a small box that outputs more energy than is input. As one example, the box can take current and voltage $I$ and $V$ as input, and output $I$ and $2\cdot V$. Or I can punch the box with 1 Joule of work, and it outputs 2 Joules of work (e.g. double the force over the same distance).

To make it less crazy, you can also consider that the box had 100% efficiency in converting energy.

What would break in reality by the existence of this box? For example, faster-than-light communication breaks causality, and allows one to send messages back in time (which constitutes as "breaking reality").

For anyone against this question, it is completely analogous to [this physics stackexchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710224/218638) about faster-than-light communication.

Comment: If this box exists, the laws of physics that we currently have are wrong. We cannot predict what would happen if we don't have working laws to make predictions. So how should we answer this question?

Comment: In Lagrangian mechanics, energy conservation is equivalent to the laws of physics being time translation invariant.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I literally give an example of what I'm asking. If I ask what faster-than-light communication would break, the answer isn't "we believe it's impossible, your question is useless", the answer is "it would break causality and allow you to send messages back in time". I'm asking an analogous question for the 2nd law of thermodynamics. We believe it, but what in reality would break if an alien box went against it? Or could such a device fit comfortably in our world without breaking reality? 
J.G. gives a more compelling answer, which I appreciate.

Comment: Combining what Marius & J.G. said, if you don't have time invariance, it throws a spanner in the works of *all* prediction and retro-diction. That makes it really difficult to formulate any consistent laws of physics.

Comment: I understand what you were asking, and I agree that @J.G. gave a more concrete perspective. Please note that I never said anything about not believing in this hypothetical box, or that your question is useless. I am merely pointing out that your question is of the type "What can current physics say about a phenomenon that goes against current physics?" I think you agree that current physics cannot answer such questions.

Comment: And to comment on your example, are you sure that "it would break causality and allow you to send messages back in time" is a good answer to the FTL questions? What empirical evidence do we have to back up such an answer? It is just a guess.

Comment: If the box returns twice the energy that's put into it, it's not 100% efficient -- it's 200% efficient.  Assuming 100% efficiency assumes no loss **and no gain**.

Comment: I agree with @MariusLadegårdMeyer here. This question of the type "*What do the laws of physics say would happen if the laws of physics weren't true*" cannot be answered. Your answer to faster-than-light communication is of the same type and also cannot be answered - the answer that you provide focuses specifically on a single feature that would change and ignores all other consequences which would cause a total break-down of the laws of physics which would cause the world to never have existed (as we know it) and thus for the attempted answer to have no meaning apart from the philosophical.

Answer (score 1):

If you could do that, input 1 J and output 2 J, you could build some setup that transfers that output and loops it back around to the input, creating a feedback loop (2 J, 4 J, 8 J, 16 J....).  This energy would quickly swell to a supernova that destroys the universe (or at least until your feedback mechanism is destroyed).

Bertrand Russell once said a single false proposition can then be used to prove *any* conclusion. As example, given:
$$ 1 = 0 $$
prove you are the Pope.

Proof:

Given $$1=0$$
Add 1 to both sides
$$2=1$$

The set of {myself, the Pope} contains 2 elements. By the previous result,  $2=1$, so the set contains 1 element, and it contains both the Pope and me.

Therefore, I am the Pope.

I think your free energy box is the physical equivalent of $1=0$.  So you ask what rule of reality is broken by it. The answer is, potentially, all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you could have devices having 100% or even more than 100% energy efficiency , then you can easily break the first as well as second law of thermodynamics and cool your ice-cream while sitting inside sun without much external effort .

Comment: Made me laugh. Up voting

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of energy is tied by Noethers principle to the fact that the laws of physics now are the same as the laws of physics in the future. This symmetry would then be broken by the box. Do things like the reversibility of thermodynamis breaks down.

Answer (score -1):

it depends on how it works.

assuming it was kind of accelerator that consumes no energy for acceleration (or less than usually needed), like a unballanced wheel or using some matter that has  active gravitational mass different than passive gravitational mass. then, the only effect is that we'll realise that these laws were false.

but if that was happening through some loophole in the known physic's laws then nothing will change.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).